# Passing an array and a variable to a function in Perl

Tags: perl

I have an issue passing an array and a variable to a function. For example, I have the following.

```
 my @the_array = ("hello", "hey");
 CallFunction(@the_array, "random")


 sub CallFunction{
     my (@array_ref, $ran_variable) = @_;

     foreach $element (@array_ref){
         print $element ."\n";
     }
 }
```

I would want the following output

```
hello
hey
```

But I get the other variable in the output, and I don't know why.

```
hello
hey
random
```

Comment: What you call `array_ref` is an array, not an array reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following assignment will put all the values in parameter list `@_` into `@array_ref`:

```
my (@array_ref, $ran_variable) = @_;
```

You have two options.

1. Reorder the passing of parameters, so that the array is at the end:

   ```perl
   my @the_array = ( "hello", "hey" );
   CallFunction( "random", @the_array );

   sub CallFunction {
       my ( $ran_variable, @array ) = @_;

       for my $element (@array) {
           print $element . "\n";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or pass the array by reference:

   ```perl
   my @the_array = ( "hello", "hey" );
   CallFunction( \@the_array, "random" );

   sub CallFunction {
       my ( $arrayref, $ran_variable ) = @_;

       for my $element (@$arrayref) {
           print $element . "\n";
       }
   }
   ```

Minor Note — Naming a normal array `@array_ref` is a little confusing.  Save the `ref` suffix for variables actually holding references.